# XCode C Project Does not Show Folder "Tree"

Tags: c, xcode

I am having a hard time creating a C application in XCode with a hierarchical file tree.  What should I do here?  I have created a directory called structs and added a linked list file (C & H) to it, but in the project navigator it does not show the tree.  How do I display the tree as is?  Also why does it take several steps to add a directory, is there a cleaner way?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Fyi, `linked_list` != `linked_list.h`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your `#include` statement is incorrect.

However, once you've fixed that, you can tell Xcode to show you the disk structure of your code by adding the folders to Xcode instead of the files. To do that, go to the file menu and select "Add Files To …". In the "Add Files" dialog, make sure the radio button named "Create Folder References" is checked. Then select the folder you want Xcode to show you in the navigator, rather than the files, and click the "Add" button. You'll now get a blue folder, and Xcode will show all files that are in the folder. It will attempt to compile or copy all of them, as well.

Comment: Thanks fort the answer.  I tried that, and I selected the folder called "structs" and clicked add but it says "The file “structs” doesn’t exist.".  Is it not understanding that its a folder and not a file?  http://imgur.com/QFuGs90,UCMPqtX#1 http://imgur.com/QFuGs90

Comment: Can you copy the entire text of the error and explain the context in which you're getting the error in more detail? Where are you seeing this error? Also, did you remove the existing references to linked_list.c and linked_list.h from the Xcode project?

Comment: I restarted the project from scratch and followed your solution and it worked.  Thanks,.